# Two vertical side by side views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering how to do two vertical side by side views in Android where one side is Google Calendar and the other side Google task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take two layouts inside one parent layout(may be LinearLayout with horizontal orientation), then give **android:layout_weight="1"** for both the child layouts or views.So i think it may make it work.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer Thanks for the complement.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Activity with two [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). The sample application [FragmentBasics](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) illustrates how fragments are used.